# How to handle manually deleted then recreated Hosted Zone in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

so my team manage a Route53 Hosted Zone via Cloudformation. However, a recent cloudformation deployment failed due to 'AWS::Route53::HostedZone' with a specific identifier not found. I can find this hosted zone in the console, but with a different identifier. After some digging, I found that a teammate manually deleted this resource before creating it again, but the new physical ID has not been picked up by the Cloudformation, hence throwing not found error in deployment.

I've read a few AWS documentations on how to deal with this situation, for example, [this one](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/failing-stack-updates-deleted). However, I'd like to confirm by removing this resource from cloudformation before adding it back, will this create a new Hosted Zone? Or will redeployment pick up the existing Hosted Zone without creating a new one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html this is the only way to have an existing stack own something it didn't create

Comment: Thanks, importing an existing resource into CloudFormation is the way to go.